# LightBox not Calling html form

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a simple example i am using FancyBox for the light box. I have a form configure to use FancyBox. One link is a picture that shows up in the light box when i click it, that works perfect for me. I also have a simple .html form however when i click on it, it doesn't show in the lightbox nor is it redirected to the form. Under is my code:

**Menu Form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fancyBox - Fancy jQuery Lightbox Alternative | Demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.2"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" media="screen" />

    <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

    <!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

    <!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.4"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#regForm').click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'href' : 'form.html'
                    });

                return false;
            });

            $('#pic').click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'href' : 'http://en.gtwallpaper.com/fondecran/chiens/chiens_01.jpg'
                    });

                return false;
            });

        });


    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <a id ="regForm" href="form.html" >form</a>

    <a id ="pic" href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ZdjEZ8qqBq0/UA2dNK8JYDI/AAAAAAAAAJ8/31bh4BzcA6E/s400/Dog-1.jpg" >dog</a>


</body>
</html>
```

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <label>Name</label><input type="text" />
    <label>Password</label><input type="text" />
    <input type="submit"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you have to use the `click()` method?

If not, this simple script works for both the `image` and the `form` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Now, in the specific case of the `form`, since this is an external html document you have to tell fancybox the `type` of content that has to be open so, in your html you could do

```
 <a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="form.html" >open form</a>
 <a class="fancybox" href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ZdjEZ8qqBq0/UA2dNK8JYDI/AAAAAAAAAJ8/31bh4BzcA6E/s400/Dog-1.jpg" >open dog image</a>
```

**NOTICE** the additional class `fancybox.ajax` where we let fancybox know the `type` of content. Please also notice that you could use `ajax` if the html document is within the same domain or `iframe` if it is in another domain (where you should have to have access too) so

```
 <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="form.html" >open form</a>
```

Last NOTE : `ajax` won't work locally, you have to test it in a server.

Comment: I am using Spring Mvc application any advise on how to request the form since it's request will be handled by the Controller

Comment: this works great wish i could give you more points for this answer

Comment: i have one problem i am not seeing the close button on my view i added the  'showCloseButton' : true and still its not there. The fancybox_sprite.png is in the same directory as the css file, can you render some help

Comment: @dev_darin : if you share a link I can find it for you ;)

Comment: ... also, make sure that you are not using the option `modal:true`

Comment: no i am not using modal:true the button seems to be there i am seeing in firebug its no found on my server. I may need to set an updated url to the file in the fancybox.css